# How to use UART for console and other UART peripheral for expansion boards on 3 model b v1.1

Tags: uart, serial-console

I don't have SSH access or a dedicated external monitor and keyboard for this raspberry pi, so I would prefer to have serial access, which I have working with a device-tree overlay.  The thing is, I ALSO need a uart device to talk to an expansion board.

I just flashed the latest OS, `2017-03-02-raspbian-jessie-lite.img`, and have been reading through tutorials on getting serial access, but not necessarily serial access WITH another serial port.  I don't care about bluetooth at all and only require a moderate (`115200 bps`) baud rate.

How can I get serial console on `/dev/ttyAMA0` and serial access to my other board on `/dev/ttyS0`?

https://www.abelectronics.co.uk/kb/article/1035/raspberry-pi-3-serial-port-usage

http://spellfoundry.com/2016/05/29/configuring-gpio-serial-port-raspbian-jessie-including-pi-3/

Comment: Is the lack of ssh access due to the pi not being connected to the Internet? If so you could setup the pi as an access point and simply connect to the ap and ssh in that way. You could also open a console through Bluetooth. I believe an ap is probably the easiest, given you aren't using the wifi.

Comment: Unless you are using the compute module you will need to bit bang to get extra serial ports or use a USB serial dongle.